# Switch between windows Selenium Webdriver Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I have a webapp that when it loads creates a new page to load content,
I am using selenium to try and create a few tests for the web application, but cannot switch to the newly created webpage, I am using JavaScript and mocha to create these test, below is my current code,

```
    var assert = require('assert'),
    test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
    webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.ie()).build();
    test.describe('open Page', function() {
      this.timeout(15000); //Set timeout to 15000ms
      test.it('load page', function(done) {
        var status=driver.get('http://localhost:58080/TC1');
        assert.equal(status,status);
        done();
      });

    });
    test.describe('title', function() {
    test.it('get page title',function() {
      console.log(driver.getWindowHandle().size);
      var title = driver.title;
      console.log("Title of the page before - switchingTo: " + title);
      assert.equal(title,'TC1');
    });
});
```

but each time I get an error as below

> open Page
>       V load page (3702ms)
>
> title undefined Title of the page before - switchingTo: undefined
>       1) get page title
>
> 1 passing (4s)   1 failing
>
> 1) title get page title:
>        AssertionError: undefined == '[TC1]'

Am i missing something major?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as `driver.title`. You have to use `driver.getTitle()`. For instance:

```
driver.getTitle().then(function (title) {
    assert.equal(title, 'TC1');
});
```

Note that you should not have to use the `done` if you use the testing functions provided through Selenium. Selenium patches `it` so that it waits for the control flow.

Also, this does not make sense:

```
var status=driver.get('http://localhost:58080/TC1');
assert.equal(status,status);
```

The return value of `driver.get` is not a *status*, it is a promise. Testing that the promise is equal to itself is useless.

Comment: I am using the "var status=driver.get('http://localhost:58080/TC1');
assert.equal(status,status);"

 Just to log that the page has been opened

Comment: By the time `assert.equal` runs, your page may not have been opened yet. You should spend some time learning how promises work.